# Network links in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I mail people network links in Microsoft Outlook using

```
file:O:\folderA\folderB\fileC.txt
```

For most people, clicking this link will open the folder.
However some people get a 'cannot find file' message, even though they can access the file through windows explorer. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, everyone's computer must have that network drive mapped to the drive letter "O". Is this the case already?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be file:// and using all forward slashed from there, starting witha forward slash in front of the drive letter? e.g.

```
file:///O:/folderA/folderB/fileC.txt
```

Comment: no, double or triple slashes don't help either

Comment: How do you add these hyperlinks to the mail? Do you type the adress yourself? Or do you use the menu to add a hyperlink and give the target? Or do you type the path and then select it and make it a hyperlink with the anchor button?

Comment: just type - the issue is, it works for most people, but just not for some, and its not a question of drive mappings or access

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a specific windows/outlook version? Seems to go wrong in the way the link is parsed. Maybe you can try to find out what Outlook is trying to open and see if the path and filename are still the same as what you typed?